# Proving that $\mathbb{Q}[X] = (X-1) + (X+1)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, ring-theory, proof-explanation, ideals

> Prove that $I+J = \mathbb{Q}[X]$ with $I$ and $J$ ideals in $\mathbb{Q}[X]$ where $I=(X-1)$, $J=(X+1)$.

I was thinking something along the lines of
$I+J=(1)$ because they are coprime. That means
$$
  I+J
= \{1 \cdot a \mid a \in \mathbb{Q}[X]\}
= \{a \mid a \in \mathbb{Q}[X]\}
= \mathbb{Q}[X].
$$

I'm not sure if this is a proper proof for this problem.

This is the proof suggested by my professo, but I can't really figure where the $1/2$ comes from.
[image: A proof suggested by my professor]
I should've formated it on the website but it would take me a long time to do so.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your questions (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The number $\frac{1}{2}$ is an element of $\mathbb{Q}[x]$. Hence, you can multiply any element of an ideal contained in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ by $\frac{1}{2}$ and the result will remain in the ideal by definition of ideal.

What your professor has proved is that $1=-\frac12(x-1)+\frac12(x+1)$, which is an element of $I+J$ by definition of the ideal. This is sufficient to show $I+J=\mathbb{Q}[x]$ since the inclusion $I+J\subseteq \mathbb{Q}[x]$ is rather trivial.

Comment: Ohhh I wasn't paying enough attention. Thanks for explaining it.

Answer (score 0):

Observe simply that

$$-\frac12(x-1)+\frac12(x+1)=1\implies I+J=\Bbb Q[x]\;$$

I think your professor was doing something like this, but I don't quite follow in romanian...:)

Comment: Turns out that the OP's professor gave this solution, but he doesn't understand it.

Comment: @Batominovski I saw the proof: it isn't quite the same...

Comment: @Alex Remember: if an ideal of a unitary ring contains the unit $\;1\;$ , then it is the whole ring.